# How to mirror one axis in raylib?

Tags: c++, graphics, raylib

[Change in coordinate system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Ti2.png)

I am creating a game using the raylib library in c++. By default, raylib's coordinate system (top) origin is at the top-left corner of the screen with the positive x-direction towards the right and the positive y-direction down. I wish to have a coordinate system (bottom) with its origin at the bottom center of the screen with the positive x-direction towards the right and positive y-direction up.

Using Camera2D, I am able to get the correct translation and scaling for the game coordinate system. However, I am unable to align the axis how I want. That is, either the x-axis or y-axis is reflected. Is there any way to reflect only a single axis?

Note: I understand I can simply use negative values on one axis to get the desired effect. Though, that is impractical for my purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by using `rlgl.h` functionality rather than the Camera2D system. Specifically, the `rlScalef` function allows for scaling each axis individually, rather than just the single `zoom` attribute of Camera2D.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to copy the `BeginCamera2D` functions and modify them to apply a rotation to the camera matrix.